# 2D Blur convolution with separable kernel

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

I am trying to make blur convolution with custom `float` array.

My array is defined as `float array[width*height]`. I edited [these](https://www.programming-techniques.com/2013/03/gaussian-blurring-using-separable-kernel-in-c.html) functions, so it can work with custom array, and not only OpenCV `cv::Mat`

My code looks like this:

```
int reflect(int M, int x)
{
    if(x < 0)
    {
        return -x - 1;
    }
    if(x >= M)
    {
        return 2*M - x - 1;
    }

    return x;
}

void separable2DConvolution(float * data, Size dataSize, float *kernel, int kernelSize)
{
    // make copy of original image
    float * dataCopy = new float[dataSize.width()*dataSize.height()];
    memcpy(dataCopy, data, dataSize.width()*dataSize.height());
    float * temp = new float[dataSize.width()*dataSize.height()];
    memcpy(temp, data, dataSize.width()*dataSize.height());

    float sum;
    int x1, y1;
    int kernelRadius = floor(kernelSize/2);

    // along y - direction
    for(int y = 0; y < dataSize.height(); y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < dataSize.width(); x++){
            sum = 0.0;
            for(int i = -kernelRadius; i <= kernelRadius; i++){
                y1 = reflect(dataSize.height(), y - i);
                sum = sum + kernel[i + kernelRadius]*dataCopy[y1*x+y1];
            }
            temp[y*x+y] = sum;
        }
    }

    // along x - direction
    for(int y = 0; y < dataSize.height(); y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < dataSize.width(); x++){
            sum = 0.0;
            for(int i = -kernelRadius; i <= kernelRadius; i++){
                x1 = reflect(dataSize.width(), x - i);
                sum = sum + kernel[i + kernelRadius]*temp[x1*y+x1];
            }
            data[x*y+y] = sum;
        }
    }

    delete [] temp;
    delete [] dataCopy;
}
```

Array is passed to `separable2DConvolution` as `data`, `Size` is custom class with defined width and height (both are valid and greater than 0), `kernel` is **normalized Gaussian array** (almost same as the one from `cv::getGaussianKernel`) and `kernelSize` is size of Gaussian array (I'm using size 11).

I use this function to replace `cv::sepFilter2D` from **OpenCV**, but somehow, output is different.  After using my function, I am converting image to see difference.

OpenCV output has (as expected) "blurred" values, but with the very same input passed to my function, the first third is noised (not blurred at all) and the other part of image is intact.

What's problem with my code?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subscripting for saving the pixel sums is wrong.  `temp[y*x+y]` will write all the results for the first column to the first pixel (`temp[0]`).  Many other pixels will be unchanged.  You probably want `temp[y * dataSize.width() + x]`, with a similar change for `data[x*y+y]` in the next loop and when calculating subscripts to read the pixel values.

Unrelated, you don't need to `memcpy` the bitmap to make copies since you should be writing to every pixel in the image.  You don't need `dataCopy` at all, since the original `data` array hasn't been changed yet.

Using `floor` is overkill for an integer.  Since `kernelSize` is positive, you can just say `int kernelRadius = kernelSize / 2;` since this will round down.